# Another ASP to MVC migration > routes

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-routing, maproute

Migrating our classic ASP site to ASP.Net 4.5 MVC.  Our site is pretty large, hundreds of file, and SEO optimized.  All URLs are SEO friendly, via web.config, eg.:

`www.ourdomain.com/articles/2013/120/the-best-article`

`www.ourdomain.com/blog/2013/122/the-best-blog`

`www.ourdomain.com/video/2013/123/the-best-video`

ie. www.ourdomain.com/{contenttype}/{year}/{id}/{url encoded title}

The ASP files to render are stored in a folder like /render/content.asp

We don't want to change any URLs in this migration.  The new files of the MVC app will be in all new directories than the existing site.  For example, a view: /MVC/content.vbhtml

How would you go about adding links in your Views, with ActionLink or other, to use the existing SEO friendly path instead of the default path, without hardcoding the path in the links in the view (adopt from currently URL, more or less).  For example:

@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", New With {.id = currentItem.ID})

That creates an Edit link like : /MVC/Edit/120

But, what I would like is:  /article/edit/120.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
@Html.RouteLink("Edit", "myRouteName", New With { ... route params ... } );
```